# Wrong output inet_ntop

Tags: c, network-programming, getaddrinfo, inet-ntop

I'm trying to print an ip address from inet_ntop, but the output seems pretty weird.

The program seems to work well, I succeed to connect the socket but it print this:

```
H��H9�u�H�[]A\A]A^A_�ff.�
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    struct addrinfo hints, *result;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    hints.ai_flags = 0;

    int s = getaddrinfo("irc.root-me.org", "6667", &hints, &result);
    if( s != 0){ 
        printf("erreur\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   

    int f = connect(sock, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
    if(f != 0){ 
        printf("erreur connect\n");
    }   

    struct sockaddr_in *sockin;  
    sockin = (struct sockaddr_in *)result->ai_addr;
    char  *dst;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sockin->sin_addr, dst, sizeof(char *));
    printf("%s\n", dst);
    freeaddrinfo(result);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answer, I get it : never store anything in a pointer ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. The 3<sup>rd</sup> parameter to `inet_ntop()` should be a `char`-array or a pointer to the 1<sup>st</sup> element of a `char`-array.
2. The 4<sup>th</sup> parameter to `inet_ntop()` should be the **size** of the destination buffer, whose address is passed as 3<sup>rd</sup> parameter.

What you do is to pass the uninitialised `char`-pointer `dst` as destination and tell the function it would point to `sizeof(char*)` bytes memory.

An `AF_INET` address (which has the form `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`) uses a maximum of 4x3 characters plus 3 delimiting `.` `char`s which sums up to 15 `char`s plus 1 additional `char` used as `0`-terminator to make it a C-"string", so the corrected code would look like this:

```
char dst[16] = ""; /* inet_ntop() does not necessarily 0-terminates the result. */
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sockin->sin_addr, dst, sizeof dst);
```

As pointed out by *[Filipe Gonçalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2793118/filipe-gon%C3%A7alves)* in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222273/wrong-output-inet-ntop/31222361?noredirect=1#comment50444835_31222361) one can use `INET_ADDRSTRLEN` (if available) instead of the hard coded  "magic number" `16` to define the buffer size for the textual representation of a IPv4 address. It's a good thing.

---

Documentation for `inet_ntop()` is here:

- [POSIX in general](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_ntop.html#)
- [Specific to Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html)

Comment: Good answer, but I would suggest using `INET_ADDRSTRLEN+1` (defined in `arpa/inet.h`) as the size of the buffer (or `INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+1` if working with IPv6).

Comment: It's me again, I read your answer and it really helped me but I don't understand how you figured out that the third parameter should be an array instead of a pointer? Is this the **const** that tell you this?

Comment: I read your comment and it really helped me but I don't understand how you figured out that the third parameter should be an array instead of a pointer? Is this the **const** that tell you this ?

Comment: Please see the documentation. I added the links to it.

Answer (score 2):

### The Problem

The problem is with the size of the destination char* you're trying to save the result in, and the fact that it is uninitialized, what you want to do is save it in a char[].

sizeof(char*) on x86 is 4B and 8B on x64, IP Addresses are usually larger than that (an IPv4 address is between 7 to 15 bytes) + 1 for null terminator.

### Solution

You can fix the code as follows:

```
char dst[16] = {0};
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sockin->sin_addr, dst, sizeof(dst));
```

After the fix:

```
$ ./main
212.83.153.145
```

### Source Code

If you want the full fixed main.c, I've [uploaded it to github.](https://github.com/mtnmts/stack_overflow_solutions/blob/master/31222273-wrong-output-inet-ntop/src/main.c)

Comment: Storing other types in a pointer is in general wrong; it is not just the size of the pointer, but just the wrong data type and has nothing to do with the size of the pointer.

Comment: Just a hint: you should not post the full prompt, as that might show more than you want to exhibit.

Comment: I added a mention that it's the wrong type to use, thanks for fixing the prompt.

Comment: Welcome. But it's still in the edits - the web does not forget.

Comment: More importantly people will not get a bad answer.